# Solar UV index radiation sensor?

Tags: arduino, sensor, uv

I need to measure solar [Ultra Violet radiation index](http://www.who.int/uv/intersunprogramme/activities/uv_index/en/index.html).

Is there any light sensor that would allow me to do this using an Arduino?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sensitivity of ordinary Si photodiodes for UV is quite low.

There are photo detectors specialized for UV that use SiC as semiconductor material (just google for "SiC UV photodiode").

It might be possible to (ab-)use a blue SiC LED as a cheap photodiode sensitive to UV.

Comment: And what does SiC mean? // Silicon Carbide:[source](http://www.boselec.com/products/documents/SG01S-18_2010BEC.pdf)

Comment: Yes, SiC is Silicon Carbide. It is a wide bandgap semicondictor material.